# Having trouble accessing an attribute of a private type

Tags: ada

I'm using Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors to implement vectors, but whenever I do something like:

```
size := myVector'Length;
```

I get this error:

```
prefix for "Length" attribute may not be private type
```

How can I access this attribute?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors` defines a function for getting the Length. It is called `Length`.

So, in your code:

```
size := myVector.Length; -- Ada 2005/2012
size := myVectorPackage.Length (myVector); -- Ada 95
```

The Attribute `'Length` is only valid for array types.

Comment: Ah, stupid me. I was misreading the instructions this whole time. I guess I just needed another set of eyes. Thank you.